# How to type after auto complete in XLS?

Tags: microsoft-excel, autocomplete

When I type something, the regular Excel autocomplete suggests a match.
If I click enter it completes and exits the cell. Just using a right arrow exits as well.

Can I accept the auto complete and go to the end of the cell to type after it without exiting it and then having to re-open and move to its end?

MS Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the "autocomplete" you refer to is where you type a value in a list and Excel suggests a matching earlier value in the list (there is a different type of autocomplete that suggests function names and other things while you are typing a formula, but this version doesn't allow you to hit enter to accept the suggestion).

Moving to the next cell when you hit enter is an optional behaviour that applies whenever you hit enter (not just when using autocomplete). You can disable that by choosing File|Options|Advanced from the menu and unchecking "After pressing Enter, move selection". As I said, this prevent the selection moving any time you hit enter and not just when using autocomplete, so it may take some getting used to.

[image]

Comment: Thats cool if you don't want to move but it still exists typing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key does the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).